# Regex for matching groups but excluding a specific combination of groups

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match two groups in an expression, each group represents a single letter in initials as part of a name, for example in George R. R. Martin the first group would match the first R and the second group would match the second R, I have something like this:

`\b([a-zA-Z])[\.{0,1} {0,1}]{1,2}([a-zA-Z])\b`

However, I'd like to exclude a specific combination of those groups, say when the first group matches the letter d and the second group matches the letter r.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, what regex flavor?  Could you also add the example texts and expected output? Please share the code. Your regex is not correct, btw, since limiting quantifiers are placed inside a character class.

Comment: That's Solr's regex, probably using Java

Comment: Ok, try [`\b(?![dD]\.? ?[rR]\b)([a-zA-Z])\.? ?([a-zA-Z])\b`](https://regex101.com/r/mW8lV6/2). Or [`(?i)\b(?!d\.? ?r\b)([a-z])\.? ?([a-z])\b`](https://regex101.com/r/mW8lV6/3).

Comment: Awesome! First one is much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: `initials as part of a name` Regex is not for natural language parsing. Just because you think it's a name doesn't mean it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may restrict matches with a negative lookahead:

```
\b(?![dD]\.? ?[rR]\b)([a-zA-Z])\.? ?([a-zA-Z])\b
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW8lV6/2)

Note:

- The `(?![dD]\.? ?[rR]\b)` lookahead should be better placed after the word boundary, so that the check only gets triggered upon encountering a word boundary, not at every location in string
- The lookahead is *negative*, it fails the match if the pattern inside it matches the text
- It matches: a `d` or `D` with `[dD]`, then an *optional* literal dot with `\.?`, an optional space with  `?`, an `r` or `R` with `[rR]` and a trailing word boundary `\b`.

The main pattern is a more generic pattern - `\b([a-zA-Z])\.? ?([a-zA-Z])`:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?![dD]\.? ?[rR]\b)` - the negative lookahead
- `([a-zA-Z])` - Group 1 capturing an ASCII letter
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `?` - an optional space
- `([a-zA-Z])` - Group 2 capturing an ASCII letter
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary